# How to get the nextSibling after the first nextSibling?

Tags: javascript

We are able to run this code

```
str.parentNode.nextSibling.tagName
```

and get the name accordingly. What we need is the `nextSibling` after this `nextSibling` so we tried this

```
str.parentNode.childNodes[3].tagName
```

is not working? Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that an element's `nextSibling` might be a text node, which doesn't have a *tagName* property, or may not exist at all, in which case `nextSibling` will be `undefined` and trying to access its `tagName` property will throw an error.

So you likely want do to something like:

```
var nextSibling = getNextElementSibling(str.parentNode);
var tagName = nextSibling? nextSibling.tagName : ''; // or maybe undefined  

if (tagName) {
  // do stuff

} else {
  // no element sibling was found
}
```

and the `getNextElementSibling` function is something like:

```
function getNextElementSibling(node) {

  while (node && (node = node.nextSibling)) {
    if (node.nodeType == 1) {
      return node;
    }
  }
  // return undefined
}
```

Comment: you are right the space is a big issue which cause it to be undefined especially between the <td> right?

Answer (score 3):

`childNodes[3]` will return the fourth child of `parentNode`, not its second next sibling.

To get that node, you can apply `nextSibling` twice:

```
var tagName = str.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.tagName;
```

Comment: so what does this do then is it the same str.parentNode.childNodes[2].tagName ?

Comment: @user, no, it does something equivalent to `str.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[<index of str.parentNode> + 1].tagName`.