# javascript nextSibling in table

Tags: javascript, c#

First of all, I have searched and searched at many posts on this site. All the suggestions did not work. I thought this one may work but did not: [How to get the nextSibling after the first nextSibling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595100/how-to-get-the-nextsibling-after-the-first-nextsibling)

Here is the table in question:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Name")%>:</td>
    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInput" runat="server" onchange="swapIt(this);" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server" MaxLength="1000" Width="120" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbInput" runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And here is the javascript

```
function swapIt(ddlCtl) {
var inputCtl = ddlCtl.nextSibling;
inputCtl = inputCtl.nextSibling;

alert(inputCtl.nodeName);

//if (inputCtl.nodeName == "INPUT") {
if (inputCtl.nodeName == "#text") {
    if (ddlCtl.value == "-1")
        inputCtl.style.display = "inline";
    else
        inputCtl.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

This should bring back the nodeName INPUT but it brings back #text instead.
Also, need to mention this table is in a datalist inside an updatepanel and the onchange attribute is being set from the C# code behind.

I have tried so many variations of this and just can't seem to find the correct way.

Thanks!

Comment: `nextSibling` includes not only element siblings, but also text nodes, so it’s perfectly fine to find text nodes that way. Also, siblings are always on the same level, which makes `txtInput` not a sibling of `ddlInput` (it’s a child of the paren’t sibling). If you want to access your textbox and your checkbox, use `document.getElementById` to get the elements by specifying their id.

Comment: In this case that will not work. The textbox is in an ASP.Net datalist. The previous developer did not have the table, instead had the <nobr> tag which worked until I updated the page with a master page and ajax and added the table because as most know, the <nobr> tag should not be used.

Comment: If you remove the whitespace, you could try `inputCtl = ddlCtl.parentNode.nextSibling.firstChild`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately the control returned null when finding it with firstChild.